# AMP-video-docking doesn't work on iOS when served from Google AMP Cache url

Tags: amp-html, docking

When using amp-video-dock component and the AMP page is using Google AMP Caches the docking effect isn't working on iOS/safari.

For example:
https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.supereva.it/i-ragazzi-della-iii-c-che-fine-hanno-fatto-i-protagonisti-57782/amp/

I see the same behavior also on the AMP Demo

https://www.google.com/amp/s/amp.dev/documentation/examples/multimedia-animations/advanced_video_docking/preview/?format=mobile

I see that the Google cache uses the following experiments for the components

https://cdn.ampproject.org/experiments.html

But when I turned on video-dock on my browser I don't see any effect.

Any ideas about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the question. Unfortunately video docking is not supported on iOS inside the AMP Viewer due to limitations on the iOS Safari side (https://medium.com/@dvoytenko/amp-ios-scrolling-and-position-fixed-b854a5a0d451 ). I made an issue for documenting this on [github](https://github.com/ampproject/amp.dev/issues/2582).

Comment: Avoid linking to outside sources as they may go down at some point, rendering your answer useless to other users